# Adding "mode" attibute to xslt stylesheet

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xslt stylesheet which functions with no problem. I need to add the mode attribute to all xsl:template elements. What facts should I keep in mind in order to add the attribute to all elements and still have the stylesheet functioning properly. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it depends of course on the stylesheet and on the exact mode value you want to use, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes for details.

Assuming you have something like templates without a mode attribute e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <bar>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </bar>
</xsl:template>
```

and you want to use a certain mode then you have to change both the `xsl:template` as well as the `xsl:apply-templates` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="foo" mode="m1">
  <bar>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="m1"/>
  </bar>
</xsl:template>
```

On the `apply-templates` you have a different option however, you can use

```
<xsl:template match="foo" mode="m1">
  <bar>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
  </bar>
</xsl:template>
```

although with a single mode value there is no difference.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I added "mode" to all the places where I have xsl:template and xsl:template. Now the stylesheet does not function properly. I applied the same mode name in all places. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is 'I added "mode" to all the places where I have xsl:template and xsl:template' an error? I was trying to point out that you need to change `xsl:template` as well as `xsl:apply-templates`. And if you have a concrete stylesheet that fails after your attempt to add a mode then it is best (at least for me to help) that you show us the input, the original stylesheet, the new one, the output you want and the one you get.

Comment: I'd missed a template. Thank you very much for your answer.